# Where/how do I get chrome for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, google-chrome

I have looked in the default software installer but it's not there. I saved it to my downloads from the website and go to *'open the folder'* but it doesn't work.

It says *"the MIME type of this file is 'application/x-debian-package'* and can not be installed on this system. Any help?

Comment: No. That does not address my issue

Comment: It does. Read all answers again carefully.

Comment: @AlexIsaacson your title and body dont match. Either you want to download it or you want to fix the error notice. The link Goldname posted seems correct to me. That notice is a bug and needs to be reported as per : https://wiki.debian.org/MimeTypesSupport

Comment: Are we so sure that this is a duplicate? In one of the comments on the (current) first answer, OP states this is a PINE64 machine - ie, ARM-based.  Vanilla Chrome doesnt have an ARM package on the website indicated in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit [this link](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop), or, go to google and search for "chrome".

Click the download link, and choose your required version (64bit deb).

You can save it, and then afterwards open the file in Nautilus, or, just choose "Open File" with your current browser to open it with your package installer.

Comment: I already downloaded it from google. I go to open it with the default package installer and it doesn't work. It starts but stops almost immediately. I go to open it in GDebi Package Installer and it shows up "the MIME type of this file is 'application/x-debian-package' and can not be installed on this system."

Comment: Open a terminal window where the .deb file is. Do `sudo dpkg -i ./google*` and see if it gives you an error.

Comment: Just to clarify I should type
Sudo dpkg -i /home/alex/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: I'm only asking because even I know you don't mess with sudo and root commands lightly

Comment: @AlexIsaacson Yes, that's what Dorian meant. You need `sudo` in this case.

Comment: What came up after said as follows:
dpkg: error processing archive /home/alex/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ( - - install ) :
Package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/home/alex/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: What kind of hardware do you use? There does not seem to be a 64bit arm version.

Comment: I use a PINE64 single board computer

Comment: "Package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)"...Just checked the PINE64 site, and it's using ARM processors. You're going to need ARM packages (not i686 or amd64 / x86_64). I don't see an ARM package on chrome.google.com, but you may be able to get an ARM package for Chromium...Looks like there is one in Ubuntu's list (http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=chromium), so you might be able to just do a "sudo apt-get-install chromium-browser".  It's not exactly the same, but since it's what Chrome's based on, the only missing stuff should be Google-specific...

Answer (score 0):

You could also install it from Terminal:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - 
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

This will fetch the signing keys from Google's servers, then create a file that enables updating through Software Updater and `apt`, then retrieve the newest information about software versions and last but not least install Google Chrome.

You can paste this into Terminal one by one, or paste it in all at once. `chromium-browser` is the open source browser on which Google Chrome is based and is available from the Software Center by default. Chromium also works on 32-bit systems.